# PHPMailer semi issue

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a strange issue with PHPMailer, when I try to send an email I see this error: `escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons` but if I check the email, I can see that the email is sent, how can I fix/hide this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code that's it, hope it will help:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$name = 'Your Name';
$to = 'to@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Hello World!';
$message = 'This is a test mail!';
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'yourmail@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '*********';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->addReplyTo($to, $name);
$mail->setFrom($to, $name);
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->msgHtml($message);
$mail->send();
```

Simply change email & password and run.

> Hope you included PHPMailer library in root, if no then also check the path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP installation has disabled that function, but it's probably a warning rather than an error so it's continuing to run your code and sending your mail. You control the display of PHP errors & warnings in your php.ini file, look at the `error_display` property.

A better solution is to use SMTP to localhost, which does not require the use of this function. It's also faster and safer than using PHP's `mail()` function, which is what PHPMailer uses by default. To change, just add this to your existing PHPMailer code:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
```

Comment: @Syncro The problem is that I can't install local email server on my shared hosting.

Comment: If `mail()` works, you already *have* a local mail server, and it's entirely normal for shared hosts to provide one. I've no idea why anyone uses shared hosting any more. It's horrible to deal with and isn't really any cheaper - you can get a complete, functional server for €3/month with full root access.

Comment: @Syncro I'm a bit poor I don't have much money..., anyway is possbile that this problem is generated by the port of the server?

Comment: No, if you're using mail() it doesn't use a port - it calls a local sendmail binary via a shell - which is potentially dangerous in a shared hosting environment. Since sendmail itself (hidden from you) talks to localhost on port 25, I would expect your SMTP connection to work with the same settings. Alternatively, refer to your host's docs, as they should tell you how you should send email.